# SQLITE update ROW not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

im trying to update specific row  but no luck.
**Im first time working with sqlite, maybe its true im confused with column/row
In ideal i want update text in field with name MESSAGE_HISTORY(id=5)
Same way and code works for field Item0 (id = 1)**

```
public static void updateHistory(ArrayList<MessageModel> models, String id) {
        if (database != null) {
            Cursor c = database.query(TDatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE,null,null, null, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    int index1 = c.getColumnIndex(MESSAGE_HISTORY);//return position 5
                    ContentValues data = new ContentValues();
                    data.put(MESSAGE_HISTORY, DatabaseHelper.chatHistoryModelsConvert(models, id).toString());
                    long k = database.update(TDatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, data, "id=" + index1, null);
                    DBLogger.w("DATABASE UPDATE STATUS = "+k);
                  }while(!c.moveToFirst());
            }else {
                DBLogger.d("Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

`K` always return 0
Any help ?
**[UPD]**

```
public static void CreateDB() {
        if (database != null) {
            Cursor c = database.query(TDatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            if (!c.moveToFirst()) {
                cv.put(TDatabaseHelper.ITEM0, "Item0"); // <---- this item update very good index = 1
                cv.put(TDatabaseHelper.MESSAGE_HISTORY, "history"); <-- cant update, index = 5;
                cv.put(TDatabaseHelper.ITEM1, "item1");
                cv.put(TDatabaseHelper.ITEM2, "item2");
                cv.put(TDatabaseHelper.ITEM3, "item3");
                long rowID = database.insert(TDatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
                DBLogger.i("row inserted, ID = " + rowID);
            }
        }
    }
```

[UPD]
this not help :(

```
  String[] args = new String[]{""+index1}; ??database.update(TDatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, data, "id=?", args);
```

Comment: Check out the value of `index1`. And this: `while(!c.moveToFirst()` looks very strange to me. I'd use something like `while(c.moveToNext()`

Comment: `String[] args = new String[]{id};
database.update(TDatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, data, "id=?", args);`

Comment: @Rotwang value of index1 = 5;

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya {id} = index1 ?

Comment: And what about the second part of my comment? Moreover, is `index1 = 5` at any iteration of your loop? Then a loop is useless. Simply fire an update which updates ALL the rows *where `index1 = 5`*.

Comment: @Rotwang i have only one column in table. And if set while(c.moveToFirst) than its always tried to update in logs and app not response(lags)

Comment: Which seems quite obvious. Did you ever use a database before? It seems to me that this is your very first time.

Comment: @Rotwang yep first time using.  i add code how i create table . Any way for ROW = 1 update work, for ROW =5 update not working.

Comment: You are confusing the column index and the row ID.

Comment: The problem is not in how you create the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line gives you the index of the column named `MESSAGE_HISTORY` but it does not give you the value.

```
int index1 = c.getColumnIndex(MESSAGE_HISTORY);//return position 5
```

As a result of this, your line

```
 long k = database.update(TDatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, data, "id=" + index1, null);
```

updates a row that has an id of "5" and it seems that it does not exist. You need to get the value in column 5, so do something like the following:

```
String messageValue = c.getString(index1);
long k = database.update(TDatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, data, 
    MESSAGE_HISTORY + " = ?", new String[] {messageValue});
```

It is better to use the `whereArgs` here since just appending `messageValue` may cause problems. See the [update documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) regarding the `whereClause` and `whereArgs`.

In any case, slap the debugger on that last line to see exactly what you are passing to the update method. You may be surprised.

Comment: its exception which i gave on when trying u method
while compiling: UPDATE my_table SET MESSAGE_HISTORY=? WHERE id=history

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: history (code 1):

Comment: @Peter `id` is going to be the row id of the database. You seem to be conflating the row id with this field called `MESSAGE_HISTORY`. Can you explain simply what you are trying to do?

Comment: i have text in MESSAGE_HISTORY  "history", i want change "history" to  "history 2" for example.

Comment: Same way for update HOME work good. If i have tthere text "text1" and want to change to "text2" - its work, every time when i update him.

Comment: @Peter See updated code in answer. It uses the column name to update the database matching on the old value of that column and replacing it with the new value.

Comment: holy shit , its work 
String messageValue = c.getString(index1);
long k = database.update(TDatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, data, 
    MESSAGE_HISTORY + " = ?", new String[] {messageValue});
but why its not work with id=5?

Comment: @Peter You were using a column index for a row index. Your update might have worked if, instead of looking up the column index of  MESSAGE_HISTORY you looked it up for "_id" (I think that is the name.) You would then use that column index to retrieve the row number using `c.getLong()` (again, I think that's right) and using that value in your update as originally stated. You might want to go back to using the row id if you are truly only targeting a single row.

Comment: anyway big thank for information which new for me and for the help. Thank you